# Macbook Disk contains swap partition with half my disk - How to reduce swap partition

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, disk-utility, partition

[image][image]Half of my macbook disk is dedicated to a section called VM. How do i get rid of the VM section. There are only two volumes - Mac HD and Mac HD-data. No VM volume to unmount or erase. If i delete mac HD-data will that help or is there a better way

Comment: Do **not** delete `Macintosh HD - data` -- that's where all your files are. Have you tried rebooting your Mac?

Comment: have been using setup for last 6 months so rebooted regularly- Issue came up because disk was full.

Comment: What does `ls -l /private/var/vm` show? (Note: it's not especially safe to delete files there either; not sure what it does in recent versions of macOS, might or might not be ok.)

Comment: hi Gordon- I have attached a pic of ls-l for vm.

Comment: There's just a hair over 4GB of files in there; no idea why it'd be 56.9GB on disk. Next thing I'd try is starting in Recovery mode, and running Disk Utility's First Aid on everything -- volumes, then the container, then the disk. Instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210898).

Comment: Please show text output as text not images so that we can read them

Comment: Hi Gordon - Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked. Firstaid in recovery sorted it out. Apple support recommended deleting HD-Data. Appreciate your inputs